# Paid Website Code Review

Tags: software, website-review

I have written a pretty extensive webapp and it is going to go live in the next fews weeks and before I really publicize it I want to get some professionals to review it for optimization and best practices.  Is there any online service or way to find local software engineers who would be willing to do this?

Just to give some specifics that may be helpful, my site is on Google App Engine and written in Python and it is tough to find someone with extensive experience in that area.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you read this blog post from WooThemes who hired Sucuri ( http://sucuri.net/ ) to review their code. http://www.woothemes.com/2012/09/every-line-of-code-audited/

Sucuri are well known for keeping WordPress and other sites safe.

Experts are rare on oDesk or Freelance websites. You are going to find many foreigners who write code but don't really write it well, secure, or optimized. For that you really need to hire a company and if WooThemes hired Sucuri you can bet they did their due diligence and hired the best to review their framework for security, and optimization.

Comment: i agree big time with the fact its hard to find 'experts' (at a consultant level) on odesk / freelancer ect, So much so i though twice about writing it down..

Comment: @sam I know there are good coders are those sites even a good amount in the US and other major countries, but to find an expert at this type of code analysis would be difficult, time consuming, and still no guarantee.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any peers / colleagues that could have a look? The other options I could think of would be look for an expert on Odesk, Freelancer etc. Look for an outside firm that specilizes in these sort of things.

Or you could try some software like Newrelic to try and trouble shoot your app.

Comment: well I have gotten a lot of friends and co-workers to test the app for bugs and usability but they don't have much experience in the specifics of the code.  I suppose I was looking for the name of a firm but I have used freelancer in the past and gotten pretty good results